# How can I deploy an angular universal in a sub path?

Tags: angular, deployment, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy a basic angular universal app to a /sub/ folder. The page loads just find in that path, but the angular app js files does not.

I've set up an angular 17 app named `subfold` using ng cli enabling SSR. Then at `angular.json` file created a build configuration like this:

```
"insub": {
  "baseHref": "/sub/"
}
```

and a serve configuration like this:

```
"insub": {
  "buildTarget": "subfold:build:insub"
}
```

For build and serve I'm using these commands:

```
ng build --configuration insub;
node PORT=4003 dist/subfold/server/server.mjs --configuration=insub;
```

Visiting the `http://localhost:4003/sub/` in the browser, the html loads just fine but `main.js` and `polyfill.js` files fail to load.

Here is the output from the cli:

```
ERROR z [Error]: NG04002: 'main.js'
```

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I think you also have to supply `--base-href=/sub` to `ng build`

Comment: It does not make any difference adding `base-href` to the `ng build` ro in the angular.json. But removing the trailing `/` is wrong. It ignores the `base-href` and tries to load the js files from root. Like this: `http://localhost:4003/main.js`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make express engine work as expected. But here is a work around with an nginx server:

```
  location /sub/ {
    rewrite ^/sub/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
  }
```

Note that the /sub part of the url is omitted with a rewrite rule and also the proxy_pass is set to the root url not the /sub path.

Hope this will help someone.
Regards.